# Getting "You have an error in your SQL syntax" for report with parameterized query

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports

I want to generate a report using iReport. I should give Area_code, units, condition (meaning `<` `>`  `=`) as parameters. I want to get the some fields from *customer* table which satisfy the condition units `<` or  `>` or `=` number of units in *calculatedbillamounthistory* table.

As a example,

```
SELECT Cus.Cusname,Cus.Cus_Address,Cus.CusID 
FROM customer Cus, calculatedbillamounthistory Cal 
WHERE Cal.consumedunits > 90 And Cus.CusID = Cal.cusid AND Cus.Area_code = Hr0111.
```

I should pass *'>'*, *'90'*, *'Hr0111'* values as parameters.

This is my query:

```
SELECT Cus.Cusname,Cus.Cus_Address,Cus.CusID FROM customer Cus, calculatedbillamounthistory Cal WHERE Cal.consumedunits $(condition) $(units) AND Cus.CusID = Cal.cusid AND Cus.Area_code = $(Area_code);
```

When I give the query to jaspersoft it will show the error:

```
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$(condition) $(units) And Cus.CusID = Cal.cusid AND Cus.Area_code = $(Area_code)' at line 1"
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: @Markus thank u for helping me.But it's still doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JasperReports: Passing parameters to query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871042/jasperreports-passing-parameters-to-query)

Answer (score 0):

What about using the `$P!{..}` syntax for parameters, such as:

```
SELECT Cus.Cusname,Cus.Cus_Address,Cus.CusID FROM customer Cus, calculatedbillamounthistory Cal WHERE Cal.consumedunits $P!{condition} $P!{units} AND Cus.CusID = Cal.cusid AND Cus.Area_code = $P!{Area_code};
```

The `$P!{..}` syntax evaluates the parameters before executing your query. With `$P{..}` prepared statements would be used, which at least for the `condition` parameter doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use Single Value input control for condition and unit parameter and try this query in Ireport

```
  SELECT Cus.Cusname,Cus.Cus_Address,Cus.CusID 
  FROM customer Cus,calculatedbillamounthistory Cal 
  WHERE Cal.consumedunits $P{condition} $P{units} 
        AND Cus.CusID = Cal.cusid 
        AND Cus.Area_code = $P{Area_code};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can outbound whole WERE part into parameter and append this to your query:

Parameter: WHERE (String)

WHERE=" Cal.consumedunits > 90 And Cus.CusID = Cal.cusid AND Cus.Area_code = Hr0111"

SQL:
ELECT Cus.Cusname,Cus.Cus_Address,Cus.CusID 
FROM customer Cus, calculatedbillamounthistory Cal 
WHERE $P!{WHERE}