# How to pass parameters to query?

Tags: sql, jasper-reports, parameter-passing

I'm trying to write a query for my application, but I'm having some troubles. I need to pass as a parameter one field of my database, like:

```sql
SELECT name, phone, email 
FROM company 
WHERE $P{clause} = $P{key}
ORDER BY $P{order}
```

Because WHERE clause and ORDER BY clause are dynamic for the user to select.

Using `$P{}` it didn't work.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are two syntax expressions for parameter referencing in *JasperReports*: ***`$P{}`*** and ***`$P!{}`***.

- **$P{paramName} syntax** is using mostly for setting *WHERE* input parameters values. The replacement algorithm is "smart", its implementation uses [java.sql.PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html): for ***java.lang.String*** parameter the engine will replace ***$P{parameterName}*** with quoted value, for ***java.lang.Integer*** - with numeric value and so on.

The sample:

```
| Parameter name |  Parameter type   | Parameter value |
|:---------------|-------------------|:---------------:|
|   eventName    | java.lang.String  |  Olympic Games  |
|   eventType    | java.lang.Integer |       2         |
```

Original expression (to replace):

```sql
SELECT startDate, endDate, rating FROM events WHERE name=$P{eventName} AND type=$P{eventType}
```

The result will be:

```
SELECT startDate, endDate, rating FROM events WHERE name='Olympic Games' AND type=2
```

- **$P!{paramName} syntax** is using mostly for doing the "simple" replace.

The sample:

```
| Parameter name |  Parameter type   | Parameter value |
|:---------------|------------------:|:---------------:|
|   tableName    | java.lang.String  |     events      |
|   eventName    | java.lang.String  |  Olympic Games  |
|   channel      | java.lang.String  |     'BBC'       |
|   type         | java.lang.String  |     sport       |
```

Original expression (to replace):

```sql
SELECT startDate, endDate, rating FROM $P!{tableName} WHERE name='$P!{eventName}' AND channel=$P!{channel} AND type=$P!{type}
```

The result will be:

```
SELECT startDate, endDate, rating FROM events WHERE name='Olympic Games' AND channel='BBC' AND type=sport
```

---

**For more information** you can read this [Using report parameters](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/ireportwebsite/IR%20Website/ir_using_parameters.html) post and look at this [Query sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/query/index.html#query).

---

In your case the right expression may be like this:

```sql
SELECT name, phone, email FROM company WHERE $P!{clause} = $P{key} ORDER BY $P!{order}
```

where ***$P{key}*** is a ***java.lang.String*** parameter

or like this (it depends on *$P!{clause}* value)

```sql
SELECT name, phone, email FROM company WHERE $P!{clause} = $P!{key} ORDER BY $P!{order}
```

where ***$P{key}*** is a ***java.lang.String*** parameter

Comment: Important to note here is the parameter apparently needs to be a string containing multiple values, each in single quotes, separated by commas. In my testing, it doesn't seem to work without the single quotes.

Answer (score -2):

if you need to order by parameter try this:

```
SELECT name, phone, email ,(case when $P{order} = 'name' then name when $P{order} = 'phone' then phone else email end) as orderlist
FROM company 
WHERE $P{clause} = $P{key}
ORDER BY orderlist
```