# How to change a SQL KEYWORDS in a jrxml query?

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to change ORDER BY statement in a jrxml

for example

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Id = 1 ORDER BY Name ASC
```

How to change ASC dynamic?

I tried below , but it's not work

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Id = $P{Id} ORDER BY Name $P{OrderType}
EXEC sp_executeSQL 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE Id = $P{Id} ORDER BY Name $P{OrderType}'
```

I have to change it in jrxml, so I cant use code like c# or java.

Comment: Try to use `$P!{OrderType}`. Sample: `<parameter name="order" class="java.lang.String">
  <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["ASC"]]></defaultValueExpression>
 </parameter>
 <queryString>
  <![CDATA[SELECT id, name FROM product ORDER BY name $P!{order}]]>
 </queryString>`

Comment: Thinks it's worked ,please answer the question , I will choose your answer.

Comment: You can upvote my answer on [JasperReports: Passing parameters to query](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11871042/876298()) if you want :) Your post duplicates this question.