# Can we make table names dynamic in Ireport?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a requirement in IReport. In this i want to make table name as a parameter. Is it possible in ireport to pass it as a parameter? Does jasper support this?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: The *iReport* is just a gui designer for building report's templates. Are you sure that you talking about *iReport* not about *JasperReports* library?

Comment: Yes, you can. Sample: `<queryString><![CDATA[SELECT id FROM $P!{tableName}]]></queryString>`. You can read more details in [JasperReports: Passing parameters to query](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11877972/876298) post.

Comment: Thanks @AlexK, i was able to achieve this effect yesterday by following same answer your provided. I upvoted it as well. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this exemle it will help you

If parametre Type = 0 Then the choice will be Name1 ...............

```
    (
    $P{Type} == "0" ?
    "Name1" :
    $P{Type} == "1" ?
    "Name2" :
   $P{Type} == "2" ?
    "Name3" :
    "Default Name"
    )
```