# How to avoid sql injection in JasperReports without using prepareStatement

Tags: java, jasper-reports

i have a program that print reports using *JasperReports 5.5.0*. The report works perfectly but when I'm thinking about sql injection in my program i can fix it using prepareStatement. My problem is when I use JRDesignQuery to write query because it creates sql injection.

I'm stuck with code jasper report that looks like this

```
try{
        JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(PathSystem.getPath("rpt","report.jrxml"));
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserId = '" + txtUser.getText() + "'";
        JRDesignQuery newQuery = new JRDesignQuery();
        newQuery.setText(sql);
        jasperDesign.setQuery(newQuery);
        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,null, conn);
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint,false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

I can use sql injection with using input "' or 1='1" without the quotes.The sql looks like this :

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserId = '' or 1='1'
```

The report can print all UserId.

I have done research to solve it and found the way to avoid sql injection with using prepareStatement.

This is the code with using prepareStatement :

```
try {
        JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(PathSystem.getPath("rpt","report.jrxml"));
        pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserId = ?");
        pst.setString(1, txtUser.getText());
        JRDesignQuery newQuery = new JRDesignQuery();
        newQuery.setText(pst.toString().split("\\:")[1]);
        jasperDesign.setQuery(newQuery);
        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,null, conn);
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint,false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

I wonder if there are any better way to avoid sql injection without using prepareStatement instead.

Comment: This post can help you: [JasperReports: Passing parameters to query](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11871042/876298)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your reasons to avoid using prepareStatement, it is the best solution!

That said, if you want to avoid sql-injection (without using prepareStatement) you should run validations and clean `txtUser.getText()`.

For example:

1. "clean" the input from quotes by using string-replace - you can replace it with double-quotes or simply escape it!
2. if you know that the input should contain an integer, `trim()` it and validate that it's a number (you can do it in different ways: `Integer.valueOf()`, using regex, etc).

Comment: Because in my code i don't use pst.execute() to execute the query and Jasper Report just needs the statement.

Comment: @StevenGunanto got it. The following is a good read: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 0):

I understand! for any *existing-application* (that is not using PreparedStatement) it won't be easy to go and change the code at every location.

So, the best solution for you would be to use:

> [**ESAPI** : OWASP Enterprise Security API.](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API)

It will implement a layer of security before your application, thus, no code change needed.
You need to create a **Filter**, *eg.*
`public class MySecurityFilter extends ESAPIWebApplicationFirewallFilter`
and just mention it in your application's *web.xml*.
*viz.*
`<filter>`
`<filter-name>WebSecurityFilter</filter-name>`
`<filter-class>com.your.filter.class.path.MySecurityFilter</filter-class>`
`</filter>`
`<filter-mapping>`
`<filter-name>WebSecurityFilter</filter-name>`
`<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`
`</filter-mapping>`

Also, you will get a full control on the filter by creating a **policy file** that will define `<blacklist>` and `<whitelist>` of the request parameters/headers.

Comment: Yes,you got it i need to change the code at every location to use prepareStatement.What if use desktop application ? my program is totally desktop.