# iReport Jasper not working with conditional statement

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using iReports to generate some reports in my project .

I am using this line to fill the report with the parameters

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint=JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,paramMap,conn);
```

where jasperReport is an Object of `JasperReport` and I have a `Map` object `paramMap` which has a key names conditionals that carry the condition statement which I want to append in the query written in jasper Report.

Without condition the query is working fine in the reports

```
Select * from myTable WHERE 1=1
```

My condition carry multiple filter and I checked its generating properly fine and I append it to my query and run in my db enviornment properly.

The query which I use to add condition gives me a little bit of confusion.I add like this in report

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE 1=1 $P{conditionals}
```

I am not sure when this condition will executed and how to put this to run everytime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JasperReports: Passing parameters to query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871042/jasperreports-passing-parameters-to-query)

Comment: $P{conditionals} try to use prepared statement if you like string sost. use  $P!{conditionals}

Comment: @PetterFriberg I have seen that and for my case I am adding one parameter conditionals in my MAP object and passing to fillReport functiona as paramMap . This map contains a string and I want to add this String to my JasperReport query . Th filters are coming from another applications. Hope you have understand my problem.

Comment: Not really, in query (select) either you use string substitution or you use prepared statement since $P{conditionals} is not a query value your only choice is string substition  $P!{conditionals}