# Unable to Filter out the repeating values in iReport

Tags: mysql, sql, jasper-reports

I have a report that is supposed to show the `part` and `quantity` based on the `location` selected. It is a modified version of the Costing Layer Valuation in Fishbowl.

I have been able to get the location filtering to work but now the values are being duplicated and I am unable to figure out why.

These are screenshots to show the print out of the report when the Print All Repeating check box is unchecked and checked.
[image: Checked- With Repeating]
[image: Unchecked- Without Repeating]

**This is my SQL Query**

---

```
SELECT 
costlayer.qty AS Qty, costlayer.orgqty, costlayer.orgtotalcost,
costlayer.totalcost AS TotalCost, costlayer.datecreated AS DateCreated,
part.num AS PartNumber, part.description as PartDescription, asaccount.name as "InventoryAccount",
company.name AS company, currency.symbol

FROM CostLayer
LEFT JOIN Part ON part.id = costlayer.partid
LEFT JOIN Tag ON part.id = tag.partId
LEFT JOIN Location ON tag.locationId = location.id
LEFT JOIN LocationGroup ON location.locationGroupId = locationGroup.id
LEFT JOIN asaccount ON part.inventoryaccountid = asaccount.id
JOIN company ON company.id = 1
LEFT JOIN currency ON currency.homeCurrency = 1

WHERE 
costlayer.datecreated BETWEEN $P{dateRange1} AND $P{dateRange2}
AND costlayer.statusid IN ($P!{ckShowActiveCostingLayers},$P!{ckShowFulfilledCostingLayers},$P!{ckShowVoidedCostingLayers})
AND UPPER(part.num) LIKE UPPER($P{partNum})
AND (UPPER(COALESCE(asaccount.name,'')) LIKE UPPER('%' || $P{AssetAccount} || '%'))
AND LocationGroup.id LIKE $P{locationGroupID}

ORDER BY (CASE WHEN $P{AssetAccount} NOT LIKE CAST('%' AS varchar(256)) THEN asaccount.name ELSE part.num END), part.num ASC, costlayer.id, costlayer.datecreated
```

Comment: This since you join another table on the price / total table that duplicates your records, you should try to group (group by). Can not give you exact query since I do not know you data well.

Comment: If you want a precis answer you need to show the data structure... we need to know all relations between tables

Comment: @PetterFriberg Sorry i would have posted it all but Mamof seems to be famlier with Fishbowl and so i knew he understood the tables. Thank you for always being willing to help !

Comment: @PetterFriberg please check out my new question please! Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851448/combining-reports-that-use-subreports-already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In looking at your screen shots it appears it's duplicating based on the number of tags in each location. This would be from the join on tags to be able to filter the locations. By adding a distinct to your query it will weed out the duplicate database values. After doing that you'll probably want to turn back on the show duplicate values as it will then not show if you make the same quantity and value of purchases for a given part.

```
SELECT DISTINCT costlayer.qty AS Qty, costlayer.orgqty, costlayer.orgtotalcost,
costlayer.totalcost AS TotalCost, costlayer.datecreated AS DateCreated,
part.num AS PartNumber, part.description as PartDescription, asaccount.name as "InventoryAccount",
company.name AS company, currency.symbol

FROM CostLayer
LEFT JOIN Part ON part.id = costlayer.partid
LEFT JOIN Tag ON part.id = tag.partId
LEFT JOIN Location ON tag.locationId = location.id
LEFT JOIN LocationGroup ON location.locationGroupId = locationGroup.id
LEFT JOIN asaccount ON part.inventoryaccountid = asaccount.id
JOIN company ON company.id = 1
LEFT JOIN currency ON currency.homeCurrency = 1

WHERE costlayer.datecreated BETWEEN $P{dateRange1} AND $P{dateRange2}
AND costlayer.statusid IN ($P!{ckShowActiveCostingLayers},$P!{ckShowFulfilledCostingLayers},$P!{ckShowVoidedCostingLayers})
AND UPPER(part.num) LIKE UPPER($P{partNum})
AND (UPPER(COALESCE(asaccount.name,'')) LIKE UPPER('%' || $P{AssetAccount} || '%'))
AND LocationGroup.id LIKE $P{locationGroupID}

ORDER BY (CASE WHEN $P{AssetAccount} NOT LIKE CAST('%' AS varchar(256)) THEN asaccount.name ELSE part.num END), part.num ASC, costlayer.id, costlayer.datecreated
```

Comment: Is your posted SQL any different then mine posted?

Comment: Sorry, my copy from the SQL editor didn't fire and I missed the distinct on the select. I've updated it.

Comment: @PetterFriberg is right in that you could also use a GROUP BY. In this query you could simply need to copy the fields you're using in your select statement as the group by fields.

Comment: @Mamof It worked wonderfully! It was driving me insane and all i needed was one SQL function tag gah!! Thank you for not just posting the answer but for explaining why and how it worked. I appreciate that so much.

Comment: hmm, since this is correct answer you have something strange in your query you are probably joining on something that is not needed..

Comment: @Ashton my guess is LocationGroup.id LIKE $P{locationGroupID}, in your result you have multiple LocationGroup

Comment: @Mamof could you please help me with another issue i am having? It seems that my report is returning and displaying the correct quanities by locationGroup now but the issue is that it doesnt seem to be able to distinguish between inventory that used to be there and that isnt there. It's showing 6,000 items in one location when really it should be 5000 because the toher 1000 has been moved. Any thoughts :/?

Comment: Cost layers would not be what you want to look at for that sort of thing. Cost layers have no direct association with the inventory and Fishbowl does not maintain the actual cost with an individual item. The majority of accounting is based on average costing. To get an actual breakdown of the value of inventory in the given location you'd want to start with either the inventory availability or the on hand report and tie back to the part cost to get the average cost of the part.

Comment: @Mamof So is there no way i can alter the report i have to fix my issue where it is not showing me the exact items by location :/ ? thank you for helping me

Comment: @Ashton The cost layers are not the data point you should be looking at and Fishbowl does support actual costing on each individual inventory item. As mentioned you can use something like the average cost and look at your on hand inventory for a location group but that is a completely separate query.

Comment: @Mamof I figured i would need the cost layer because I still want to know the total cost of each item by location and i need to be able to filter by location. Is this possible?

Comment: @Ashton No, cost layers are created anytime inventory is entered within Fishbowl and are used to keep running totals to be used for either average, LIFO, or FIFO costing. Fishbowl does not support actual costing. You'll want to use a report that uses current inventory and add in the cost associated with your costing type, keeping in mind LIFO or FIFO will give only the next cost.

Comment: @Mamof now i understand. Thank you Mamof for taking the time to teach and explain. I appreciate that more then you know! Thanks brother

Comment: @Mamof please check out a new question i have posted- thank you!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851448/combining-reports-that-use-subreports-already