# Why does my relational tables throw OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: java, sql, jasper-reports, out-of-memory, ireport

I am using iReport to build jaspersoft reports and I am using Fishbowl as my DBMS.

I built my tables and in iReport is shows that my tables are relational but for some reason it is throwing me errors and will not run. It should be very simple. I am taking in a zipcode, date range or State Name and outputing the productName, total quantity fulfilled, zip and state abbreviation.

When I do upload the report to Fishbowl it runs but eventually crashes with an error saying it's out of memory. I do not believe this is the issue  but it is an effect of what ever is causing the report to not run correctly. Maybe it's my joins?

### Here is my SQL

```
SELECT
 STATECONST."CODE" AS STATECONST_CODE,
 ADDRESS."STATEID" AS ADDRESS_STATEID,
 ADDRESS."ZIP" AS ADDRESS_ZIP,
 SOITEM."PRODUCTNUM" AS SOITEM_PRODUCTNUM,
 SOITEM."QTYFULFILLED" AS SOITEM_QTYFULFILLED
FROM
 "STATECONST" STATECONST INNER JOIN "ADDRESS" ADDRESS ON STATECONST."ID" =     ADDRESS."STATEID"
 INNER JOIN "ACCOUNT" ACCOUNT ON ADDRESS."ACCOUNTID" = ACCOUNT."ID"
 INNER JOIN "CUSTOMER" CUSTOMER ON ACCOUNT."ID" = CUSTOMER."ACCOUNTID"
 INNER JOIN "SO" SO ON CUSTOMER."ID" = SO."CUSTOMERID"
 INNER JOIN "SOITEM" SOITEM ON SO."ID" = SOITEM."SOID"
```

### The error is:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError : Java heap space

Here are some screenshots to help as well.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this isn't the issue?  https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/java-heap-space

Comment: @AaronD i will do more work testing if that is the issue but I still doubt that that is the problem. I say that only because the amount of data I am passing is so small. I believe it is a path issue but I cant figure it out :/

Comment: @Ashton Did you check the query? How much records did you get?

Comment: @Ashton OutOfMemeory is out of memory nothing else, you get probably when working on an image, you need to check tht you have no leaks and then you can only increase memory and for jasper report use the virtualizer.

Comment: @AlexK I wasn't able to test the amount of records. When i attempted to test it in the query designer it simply said none found. Which may be because iReport honestly is not good :/

Comment: @Ashton You should check the number if records with any DB client. Did you check the Petter's solution?

Comment: @AlexK I am honestly not sure as to how to implament his solution :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have out of memory the general action is:

[Java heap space out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748432/java-heap-space-out-of-memory)

Related to jasper report it generates by default **the entire report in memory**, this can be changed using [JRVirtualizer](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRVirtualizer.html), see example in [sample reference](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/virtualizer/)

**Example** (from sample reference using file virtualizer)

```
//Create the virtualizer after 2 pages filled save in tmp director
JRFileVirtualizer virtualizer = new JRFileVirtualizer(2, "tmp");

//Preparing parameters
Map parameters = new HashMap();
parameters.put(JRParameter.REPORT_VIRTUALIZER, virtualizer);
```

Comment: How would I do this Petter? Thank you for always giving help!

Comment: Please check out my new question Petter!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36582313/wrong-number-printing-out-on-report-while-trying-to-sum-a-group-variable