# Why do I have wrong number printing out on report while trying to SUM a group variable?

Tags: sql, jasper-reports

I have made a custom report in iReport and after trying the report I have noticed that the variable I have ***Grand Total Quantity*** is not printing out the correct quantity number.

I have all of my fields placed into a group called ***"product"*** and the group's purpose is to group up all of the productNumbers (names) and then sum up each of their quantities. The variable storing the total quantities per item is ***sumTotalQuantity***

The issue is that outside of the ***Product Group Footer*** I made a variable called ***sumGrandTotalQuantity*** to SUM up the values in the ***sumTotalQuantity*** variable in the group band.

For what ever reason though the number being returned into the ***sumGrandTotalQuantity*** variable is more then the group band variable.

**Why is my variable not returning the correct variable? Is it the way I am trying to total up the group variable that is already SUMing up stuff?**

As you can see in the last photo- the actual totled quantities showing up is 173 not the 175 that is being displayed.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="SalesOrderItemsByZip" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="d4cb0e75-8b4b-4aba-9324-9be9518ac4c7">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.5"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="From" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="To" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="ZipCode" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="State" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT
    soitem.PRODUCTNUM, so.SHIPTOZIP as ZIP, soitem.QTYTOFULFILL as QTY, so.SHIPTOSTATEID as stateID, COALESCE(stateconst.code,'') AS stateabbr, so.DATECOMPLETED as soDATE, soitem.TOTALPRICE as totalAmount, soitem.typeid, company.NAME AS companyName
FROM so
    JOIN STATECONST on STATECONST.ID = so.SHIPTOSTATEID
    JOIN soitem on soitem.SOID = so.ID,
    "COMPANY" COMPANY
WHERE
    so.DATECOMPLETED between $P{From} and $P{To}
    AND (UPPER(COALESCE(stateconst.code,'')) = UPPER($P{State}) OR so.SHIPTOZIP = $P{ZipCode})
    AND soitem.PRODUCTNUM != 'SHIPPING'
    AND soitem.PRODUCTNUM != 'SAMPLE'
    AND soitem.PRODUCTNUM != 'SHIP TO CONTACT'
    AND (soitem.typeid = 10 OR soitem.typeid = 20)
ORDER BY 1]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="PRODUCTNUM" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ZIP" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="QTY" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="STATEID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="STATEABBR" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SODATE" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <field name="TOTALAMOUNT" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="TYPEID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="COMPANYNAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="sumTotalQuantity" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="Group" resetGroup="product" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{QTY}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="sumGrandTotalQuantity" class="java.lang.Double" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{sumTotalQuantity}]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0d]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="sumGrandTotalAmount" class="java.lang.Double" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{TOTALAMOUNT}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="product">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{PRODUCTNUM}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="50">
                <textField evaluationTime="Group" evaluationGroup="product" pattern="###0.00">
                    <reportElement x="175" y="0" width="50" height="20" uuid="915c3f87-127a-4ec7-8b54-136612672c46"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{sumTotalQuantity}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="375" y="0" width="75" height="20" uuid="4d241f98-7272-4c6e-bdc4-d395de916ede"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ZIP}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="479" y="0" width="75" height="20" uuid="3885c024-0db1-44f3-83c0-7f82a9d43a6c"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{STATEABBR}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="150" height="50" uuid="16730885-6808-471e-b14c-cce62c865307"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{PRODUCTNUM}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="¤ #,##0.00">
                    <reportElement x="250" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="1cc304ae-ca15-40d4-ab0c-122b6909677b"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TOTALAMOUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <title>
        <band height="50" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="25" uuid="02aceea0-791a-430c-9bb4-b6c0a62bb29a"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="16" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{COMPANYNAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="25" width="555" height="25" uuid="044c5bea-f482-4329-93d0-64433f0714a9"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="15" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Sales Order Items By Zip]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="20">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="301" y="0" width="20" height="20" uuid="e3eeac2b-12bb-43af-b133-1faeabdb0260"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[-]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="MM/dd/yyyy">
                <reportElement x="226" y="0" width="75" height="20" uuid="1c3c18a3-d58c-41a9-b157-9baecdc04a70"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{From}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="1" y="0" width="225" height="20" uuid="98522dcd-468c-4fa9-829c-e3a9349a07a4"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Date Range:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="MM/dd/yyyy">
                <reportElement x="321" y="0" width="75" height="20" uuid="29ec56c7-3aff-4119-9fcb-f533608bc9ab"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{To}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="25" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="150" height="20" uuid="b2e517f0-bd17-4b5c-a958-a6f71ecc6f3d"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Product #]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="175" y="0" width="50" height="20" uuid="fffdc077-159e-446e-b110-a8c3f8b2e3a0"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Qty]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="375" y="0" width="75" height="20" uuid="fd05ad98-c3d1-43ff-a56a-9cfe47c56a7e"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[ZIP]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="479" y="0" width="75" height="20" uuid="a15d76c6-9a14-4089-bcb8-a6f58122004f"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[State]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="250" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="30e32f6b-9477-41f9-8eef-ef27995f5cb4"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Sales Amount]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="24" width="555" height="1" uuid="eaf8a705-5cbb-4809-9345-517f1128b919"/>
            </line>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <summary>
        <band height="45">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="5" width="126" height="20" uuid="dc471d6e-e9a6-4351-9464-07b485708f0d"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Grand Total Quantity:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="25" width="126" height="20" uuid="0d772f98-e1ef-449e-9dd0-7df1c0e4071d"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Grand Total Sales:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report" pattern="#,##0">
                <reportElement x="126" y="5" width="75" height="20" uuid="450ee5e0-459b-4f7b-8990-68db5732c39d"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{sumGrandTotalQuantity}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report" pattern="¤ #,##0.00">
                <reportElement x="126" y="25" width="75" height="20" uuid="9286c874-dc26-4aff-bf27-15b2dea28b9c"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{sumGrandTotalAmount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="1" uuid="01b925b2-ff3c-4df3-a5bd-ca11defc4bf2"/>
            </line>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

---

Here is my query, screenshots of the variables and design view.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't see your jrxml, have you set correct evaluationTime on textField?

Comment: @PetterFriberg No  have not set the evaluation time. Should i? I'll try to post the JRXML too

Comment: @PetterFriberg I just posted a brand new question that is more of an SQL question and it's a tough one that I dont even think can be done. If you get time please check it out! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37079467/place-an-insert-statement-into-a-select-statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need correct [evaluationTime](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/type/EvaluationTimeEnum.html) on your textField

`$V{sumTotalQuantity}`, needs to be evaluate when your group has been terminated

```xml
<textField pattern="###0.00"  evaluationTime="Group" evaluationGroup="product">          
   <reportElement x="175" y="0" width="50" height="20" uuid="915c3f87-127a-4ec7-8b54-136612672c46"/>
   <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
   <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{sumTotalQuantity}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

`$V{sumGrandTotalAmount}`, should have `evalutationTime="Report"` (it currently works beacuse it is in the summary band, but if you move it to another band you need to set the evaluationTime.

```xml
<textField pattern="¤ #,##0.00" evaluationTime="Report">
    <reportElement x="126" y="25" width="75" height="20" uuid="9286c874-dc26-4aff-bf27-15b2dea28b9c"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{sumGrandTotalAmount}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

In iReport, select textField and set properties

[image: evaluationTime]

**EDIT**: Don't sum on other variables sum on fields

```xml
<variable name="sumGrandTotalQuantity" class="java.lang.Double" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{QTY}]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0d]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

Comment: I set my QTY textField to evaluation time Group and evaluation goup product but it is still not working :/

Comment: It seems I am still getting the wrong quantities and I have no clue why because i have done what you said :/

Comment: Are you having problem with grandtotal or group total?

Comment: My issue is with the GrandTotalQuantity. I am not sure if it is the QTY text field or my grand total honestly. All i know is that the answer printed by the grand total is always way smaller

Comment: On grand total you need resetType="Report" on variable and evaluationTime="Report" on textField

Comment: I have those set like that and still nothing :/

Comment: Try to set initial value to 0d (do not not why but I always do since I do not like null or int 0 : ), in your jrxml I can not see resetType on variable

Comment: Ping when you have done it.. in the mean time I will do some reviewing

Comment: Added the new JRXML and thank you for all of your help Petter!

Comment: ok, do not do this <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{sumTotalQuantity}]]></variableExpression> sum on the field $F{QTY}

Comment: so remove that from my JRXML?

Comment: never sum on other variables, sum on the fields.

Comment: See the edit, just sum on the $F{QTY} with resetType report and you should be ok

Comment: Perfect! Now I know not to ever sum on a variable! Thank you Petter for taking the time and for helping/teaching me!

Comment: Your welcome, back to reviewing some close votes, have fun

Comment: Petter I have another question if you could help me. I wanted to ping to see if you were available but my issue is with the same report. It seems my QTY are including the returned items so I wanted to see if there was a way to write a conditional statement with SQL to minus any item that has a soitem.status of 50 (credit return) and minus that QTY from being added. Is this posible? If so I will post a new question. Thank you!

Comment: @Ashton I can't really understand but probably you can do it jasper report as well with if statement.

Comment: Petter please check out my new question with more information please!     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655921/subtraction-between-2-conditions-in-sql-ireport