# Subtraction between 2 conditions in SQL/iReport

Tags: sql, jasper-reports

I am writing a report and everything is almost completed! The only issue I have left is one I have been unable to solve.

The report is supposed to show items by location/zipcode within a certain date range. It then uses a `GROUP` to pair up all of the `productNum`s and their `QTY`.  Their are only 2 conditions I have in place at the moment which is

```
 Where
(soitem.typeid = 10 or soitem.typeid = 20)
```

This is so that I only want to pick up Salesorder items that are `sales` (typeid = 10) or `credit returns` (typeid = 20).

My problem is that I have the dollar amounts printing off fine. It deducts the sale amount when there is a return but for what ever reason it is still treating the QTY as a positive so it says someone sold 12 items to someone when in fact they did, but the customer returned all 12.

What is showing up is:

[image]

**But this is incorrect because for the first item the QTY should be ZERO instead of 12. The Sales Amount is correct but the itemQTY is not working correctly.
Should I use a conditional statement in my SQL to fix this issue? Or is there another way?**

### Here is my SQL and JRXML code.

```
SELECT
    soitem.PRODUCTNUM, so.SHIPTOZIP as ZIP, soitem.QTYFULFILLED as QTY,so.SHIPTOSTATEID as stateID, COALESCE(stateconst.code,'') AS stateabbr, so.DATECOMPLETED as soDATE, soitem.TOTALPRICE as totalAmount, soitem.typeid, company.NAME AS companyName
FROM so
    JOIN STATECONST on STATECONST.ID = so.SHIPTOSTATEID
    JOIN soitem on soitem.SOID = so.ID,
    "COMPANY" COMPANY
WHERE
    so.DATECOMPLETED between $P{From} and $P{To}
    AND (UPPER(COALESCE(stateconst.code,'')) = UPPER($P{State}) OR so.SHIPTOZIP = $P{ZipCode})
    AND soitem.PRODUCTNUM != 'SHIPPING'
    AND soitem.PRODUCTNUM != 'SAMPLE'
    AND soitem.PRODUCTNUM != 'SHIP TO CONTACT'
    AND (soitem.typeid = 10 or soitem.typeid = 20)
ORDER BY 1
```

JRXML

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="SalesOrderItemsByZip" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="d4cb0e75-8b4b-4aba-9324-9be9518ac4c7">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.5"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="From" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="To" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="ZipCode" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="State" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT
    soitem.PRODUCTNUM, so.SHIPTOZIP as ZIP, soitem.QTYFULFILLED as QTY,so.SHIPTOSTATEID as stateID, COALESCE(stateconst.code,'') AS stateabbr, so.DATECOMPLETED as soDATE, soitem.TOTALPRICE as totalAmount, soitem.typeid, company.NAME AS companyName
FROM so
    JOIN STATECONST on STATECONST.ID = so.SHIPTOSTATEID
    JOIN soitem on soitem.SOID = so.ID,
    "COMPANY" COMPANY
WHERE
    so.DATECOMPLETED between $P{From} and $P{To}
    AND (UPPER(COALESCE(stateconst.code,'')) = UPPER($P{State}) OR so.SHIPTOZIP = $P{ZipCode})
    AND soitem.PRODUCTNUM != 'SHIPPING'
    AND soitem.PRODUCTNUM != 'SAMPLE'
    AND soitem.PRODUCTNUM != 'SHIP TO CONTACT'
    AND (soitem.typeid = 10 or soitem.typeid = 20)
ORDER BY 1]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="PRODUCTNUM" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ZIP" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="QTY" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="STATEID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="STATEABBR" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SODATE" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <field name="TOTALAMOUNT" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="TYPEID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="COMPANYNAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="sumTotalQuantity" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="Group" resetGroup="product" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{QTY}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="sumTotalSales" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="Group" resetGroup="product" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{TOTALAMOUNT}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="sumGrandTotalQuantity" class="java.lang.Double" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{QTY}]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0d]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="sumGrandTotalSales" class="java.lang.Double" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{TOTALAMOUNT}]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0d]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="product">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{PRODUCTNUM}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="50">
                <textField evaluationTime="Group" evaluationGroup="product" pattern="###0">
                    <reportElement x="175" y="0" width="50" height="20" uuid="915c3f87-127a-4ec7-8b54-136612672c46"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{sumTotalQuantity}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="375" y="0" width="75" height="20" uuid="4d241f98-7272-4c6e-bdc4-d395de916ede"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ZIP}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="479" y="0" width="75" height="20" uuid="3885c024-0db1-44f3-83c0-7f82a9d43a6c"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{STATEABBR}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="150" height="50" uuid="16730885-6808-471e-b14c-cce62c865307"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{PRODUCTNUM}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField evaluationTime="Group" evaluationGroup="product" pattern="¤ #,##0.00">
                    <reportElement x="250" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="1cc304ae-ca15-40d4-ab0c-122b6909677b"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{sumTotalSales}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <title>
        <band height="50" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="25" uuid="02aceea0-791a-430c-9bb4-b6c0a62bb29a"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="16" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{COMPANYNAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="25" width="555" height="25" uuid="044c5bea-f482-4329-93d0-64433f0714a9"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="15" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Sales Order Items By Zip]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="20">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="301" y="0" width="20" height="20" uuid="e3eeac2b-12bb-43af-b133-1faeabdb0260"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[-]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="MM/dd/yyyy">
                <reportElement x="226" y="0" width="75" height="20" uuid="1c3c18a3-d58c-41a9-b157-9baecdc04a70"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{From}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="1" y="0" width="225" height="20" uuid="98522dcd-468c-4fa9-829c-e3a9349a07a4"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Date Range:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="MM/dd/yyyy">
                <reportElement x="321" y="0" width="75" height="20" uuid="29ec56c7-3aff-4119-9fcb-f533608bc9ab"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{To}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="25" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="150" height="20" uuid="b2e517f0-bd17-4b5c-a958-a6f71ecc6f3d"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Product #]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="175" y="0" width="50" height="20" uuid="fffdc077-159e-446e-b110-a8c3f8b2e3a0"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Qty]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="375" y="0" width="75" height="20" uuid="fd05ad98-c3d1-43ff-a56a-9cfe47c56a7e"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[ZIP]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="479" y="0" width="75" height="20" uuid="a15d76c6-9a14-4089-bcb8-a6f58122004f"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[State]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="250" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="30e32f6b-9477-41f9-8eef-ef27995f5cb4"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Sales Amount]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="24" width="555" height="1" uuid="eaf8a705-5cbb-4809-9345-517f1128b919"/>
            </line>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <summary>
        <band height="45">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="5" width="126" height="20" uuid="dc471d6e-e9a6-4351-9464-07b485708f0d"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Grand Total Quantity:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="25" width="126" height="20" uuid="0d772f98-e1ef-449e-9dd0-7df1c0e4071d"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Grand Total Sales:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report" pattern="#,##0">
                <reportElement x="126" y="5" width="75" height="20" uuid="450ee5e0-459b-4f7b-8990-68db5732c39d"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{sumGrandTotalQuantity}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report" pattern="¤ #,##0.00">
                <reportElement x="126" y="25" width="75" height="20" uuid="9286c874-dc26-4aff-bf27-15b2dea28b9c"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{sumGrandTotalSales}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="1" uuid="01b925b2-ff3c-4df3-a5bd-ca11defc4bf2"/>
            </line>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Sorry Ashton I can give you good answer since I can't understand your database structure, but I can tell you that it is fairly easy to use if statement in sql IF(soitem.typeid = 10, 0, soitem.QTYFULFILLED ) as QTY, or whatever else you need

Comment: @PetterFriberg how would I do the IF statement? I want all of the items that are credit returns (soitem.typeid = 10) to be minused from the QTYFULFILLED

Comment: soitem.QTYFULFILLED*-1?, but I'm not sure of your datastructure so I'm just guessing..

Comment: @PetterFriberg Hmm I understand. I will continue to work on this and I will update you. Once again- thank you for always taking the time to look!

Comment: @PetterFriberg could you please check out my new question!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36988827/sql-subselect-statement-issue-in-ireport