# SQL subSelect Statement issue in iReport

Tags: sql, jasper-reports, subquery

I am using iReport to write custom reports and have ran into an issue.

I am attempting to alter an existing report by adding the line of code that is:

```
LEFT JOIN (select info from customfieldview where cftableid = 97022306 and recordid = so.id and cfname = 'SIN')
```

The field and table names are all correct but for whatever reason it is saying that my "WHERE" statement is messed up. Which with iReport, it's debugger usually says the issue is the line below the actual problem and the line before my WHERE statement just happens to be my subSELECT statement.

I will post my SQL and a photo highlighting my issue.

***Is my subSelect statement formatted incorrectly?***

```
SELECT (case when $P{ckShowHistoricalProductNumber} = 1 then soitem.productnum else product.num end) AS soitemproductnum, soitem.description AS soitemdescription,
(case when soitem.uomid != product.uomid then ((postsoitem.qty*uomconversion.multiply)/uomconversion.factor) else postsoitem.qty end) AS postsoitemqty,
producttree.name AS producttreename,
(CASE WHEN soitem.uomid != product.uomid then (soitem.unitprice/uomconversion.multiply)*uomconversion.factor else soitem.unitprice end) + (soitem.adjustamount / (CASE WHEN soitem.qtytofulfill = 0
                                                        THEN 1
                                                        ELSE soitem.qtytofulfill END)) AS soitemunitprice, soitem.typeid AS soitemtypeid,
company.name AS company, uom.code AS uomcode, currency.symbol

FROM soitem
LEFT JOIN postsoitem ON soitem.id = postsoitem.soitemid
JOIN postso on postsoitem.postsoid = postso.id
JOIN product ON soitem.productid = product.id
LEFT JOIN producttotree ON product.id = producttotree.productid
LEFT JOIN producttree ON producttotree.producttreeid = producttree.id
LEFT JOIN uom ON product.uomid = uom.id
LEFT JOIN uomconversion on product.uomid = uomconversion.touomid and soitem.uomid = uomconversion.fromuomid
INNER JOIN company ON company.id = 1
LEFT JOIN currency ON currency.homeCurrency = 1
LEFT JOIN (select info from customfieldview where cftableid = 97022306 and recordid = so.id and cfname = 'SIN')

WHERE postso.postdate BETWEEN $P{dateRange1} AND $P{dateRange2}
AND soitem.typeid IN (10,11,12,21,30,31,40,50,60,70,80)
AND ((COALESCE(producttreeid,0) IN ($P!{productTree1})) OR ((COALESCE(producttreeid,0) LIKE $P{productTree2})))
AND (CASE WHEN $P!{ckShowEachProductOnce} =1 then (Select first 1 producttree.id
       FROM product AS p1
       LEFT JOIN producttotree ON p1.id = producttotree.productid
       LEFT JOIN producttree ON producttotree.producttreeid = producttree.id
       WHERE p1.id = product.id
       AND ((COALESCE(producttreeid,0) IN ($P!{productTree1})) OR ((COALESCE(producttreeid,0) LIKE $P{productTree2})))) else producttree.id end) = producttree.id
```

[image]

Comment: Did you check the query (after replacing the parameters with values)?

Comment: @AlexK from what i know, the entire query worked perfectly fine until I added the subSelect line. :/

Comment: What about this query (with subselect)?

Comment: add an alias to your subquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was the way I was programming the **subQuery**.

I was using `LEFT JOIN (select info from customfieldview where cftableid = 97022306 and recordid = so.id and cfname = 'SIN')`

and saying it was a **subQuery** when in fact because it was being use in the `FROM` condition/arguement then it is actually a **Derived Table**.

I did not know there was a difference!

Thank you guys for the input and helpful tips!