# Report compiles fine but displays blank while used in Fishbowl

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have a report that runs and complies perfectly fine while in iReport.
The report has 1 `main report` and 2 `subreports`. They work fine and each compile individually and as a unit (when the main report is ran).

The issue is when I upload the report to Fishbowl my report runs but everything in the detail band is blank.

I have the subreport expressions the exact same as the other reports I have built before - and it has worked perfectly fine.

***Can anyone think of a reason as to why this may be happening?***

This is a photo displaying and if anyone needs any more information/code let me know and I will gladly post.

***I HAVE UPDATED WITH A NEW PICTURE OF SOME ERRORS I HAVE FOUND- PLEASE TAKE A NEW LOOK- THANK YOU!***

---

[image]
[image: Fishbowl Report Display]

Comment: When uploading the report it doesn't upload the subreports. You'll have to copy those over to the server/reports/custom directory

Comment: @Mamof when i upload them using Fishbowl they copy them selves to the /custom folder on the server. I've checked.

Comment: @Mamof I have done what you suggested and still no luck :/

Comment: @Mamof any idea :/ ?

Comment: Check that you have correct absolute path to sub reports.

Comment: @PetterFriberg I do. That's the thing :/ I am using the same path as the other subreports ive built in other reports "./Custom/" + "subreport.jasper"

Comment: Other sub report with same path are working?... normally you pass as parameter with the absolute base path.. Try to set the whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" in subreport add a static field in title band (recompile) and check that at least the static field is visible (if not you have problem with path)

Comment: @PetterFriberg it is compiling but no data is working in the subreports when I upload them. I have no idea why it wouldn't be working when i have other subreports that are in my servers "custom" folder and I just do "./Custom/ + "subreport.jasper" and it has worked fine. This report however isnt and it's in the exact same folder

Comment: Test with static text field, if you see the text you have a problem with the datasource if not, you have a problem with path.

Comment: @PetterFriberg I added a new screenshot showing some errors- any idea what they mean? thank you Petter!

Comment: I don't think they are related but you can set whenResourceMissingType="Key" in jasperReport tag to avoid error if resource is missing.. Next time post text not image...

Comment: When running through Fishbowl it is best to use the $P{path} parameter when calling subreports as it passes through your full run path. $P{path} + "./Custom/subReport.jasper"

With that once you run it in Fishbowl make sure your server logging is set to DEBUG and it'll display any errors with pathing or the queries as they're being run to ensure the parameters are passing correctly.

With your new screen shot the reports are still compiling correctly but just don't support internationalization. When that happens I usually clear and readd my classpath JAR's and it goes away.

Comment: @Mamof please take a look at my new question- I am still having issues but it should be such an easy and quick fix. Thank you so much.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139307/passing-group-parameter-in-ireport

Comment: @Mamof also I believe I have all of the jars I need but maybe this is happening because I am missing some?

Comment: @PetterFriberg Please check out my new question!! Thank you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36267802/trouble-adding-a-producttotree-filter-to-a-report

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that happen a couple of times with Fishbowl. Here are my suggestions:

1) Try exiting Fishbowl completely, then logging back in.  I've found that if it times out and you don't exit completely, custom reports sometimes don't print.

2) Make sure your report has been created in Java, not Groovy.

3) Fishbowl does not seem to like all fonts and objects that iReport is okay with, so you may want to look at that.

4) Check your subreport directory.  Sometimes you have to manually override the .jasper file to the FB directory (Server/Reports/Custom/) if you have made changes to the subreport.

5) Sometimes FB acts finicky executing variable calculations using percentage parameters.

Hope that helps.