# Use String parameter for RegEx in query

Tags: sql-server, jasper-reports

In my query (the database is a sql server) I use a RegEx for a select command like this:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE id LIKE '1[2,3]'
```

(This query is tested and returns the data I want)

---

I want to use a paramter for this RegEx. For that I definded the Paramter in iReport `$P{id}` as a string and the value is `"1[2,3]"`.

In my query I use now this parameter like this:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE id LIKE $P{id}
```

As result I get a blank page. I think the problem is that the value of the parameter is defined with " ". But with ' ' I get a compiler error that the paramter isn't a string.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: what is returned when you run select $P{id}

Comment: Is `id` a text or numeric column? Note: The string delimiters are not part of the string value (they are part of the Java syntax) and jasper-reports will enclose the string in single quotes. E.g. `"A".length() == 1` (not 3).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Id is a numeric column.

Comment: @Blobonat Try to use `$P!{id}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JasperReports: Passing parameters to query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871042/jasperreports-passing-parameters-to-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIKE` applies to text values, not to numeric values. Since `id` is numeric use something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE id IN (12, 13)
```

with the parameter

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE id IN ($P!{id_list})
```

and supply a comma separated list of ids for the parameter. The bang (!) makes sure that the parameter will be inserted as-is, without string delimiters.

Btw: [LIKE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) uses wildcards, not regex.

You can still use `LIKE` since there exists an [implicit conversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx) from numeric types to text in T-SQL, but this will result in a (table or index) scan, where as the `IN` clause can take advantage of indexes.

Comment: I'm not sure even if it seems to be a id (integer) list that it is recommend to use this kind of string replacement, I think prepared statement is always prefeered

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works but it is using String replacement, read more about [sql-injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), to understand why this is not good practice.

The correct way to execute this `IN` query in jasper report (using prepared statement) is:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE $X{IN, id, id_list}
```

For more information as the use of `NOTIN`, `BETWEEN` ecc. see [JasperReports sample reference for query](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/query/)

Comment: SQL-injection isn't a problem for my project, because the DB is local and the data in it aren't interesting. But I agree that this can be a problem in other projects. `$X` is completly new for me. As far as I read about it, it seems to be very good solution. Thank you for your answer.