# IBM DB2 SQLException with "DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-420, SQLSTATE=22018, SQLERRMC=DECFLOAT, DRIVER=3.66.46"

Tags: db2, jasper-reports

I am working on a Jasper report using iReport 5.6 and IBM DB2 as data source. I am passing a list of strings as a parameter to the report and that is where the problem rises. The query is below;

```
SELECT customers.mobile_number, 
    COALESCE(Count(DISTINCT transaction_entries.transaction_id), 0) AS 
    number_of_transactions, 
    COALESCE(Sum(Abs(transaction_entries.amount)) / 100, 0)         AS 
    volume_of_transactions 
FROM   transaction_entries 
    JOIN customers 
      ON customers.id = transaction_entries.customer_id 
WHERE  transaction_entries.transaction_type = 'Seasonal' 
    AND transaction_entries.notification_text <> 'Notification' 
    AND customers.mobile_number IN ( $p ! {listOfMobileNumbers} ) 
GROUP  BY customers.mobile_number
```

When I try to generate the report I get the error Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlDataException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-420, SQLSTATE=22018, SQLERRMC=DECFLOAT, DRIVER=3.66.46.

Any idea why ? and the possible solution ?

Comment: According to https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n420.html your error is `THE VALUE OF A STRING ARGUMENT WAS NOT ACCEPTABLE TO THE function-name FUNCTION`, if someone asks about the error message.

Comment: I have already seen that page and did not get detailed information. The mobile_number field is returned from the database as a String and not a DECIMAL.

Comment: Maybe `mobile_number` is a non-string field and you are passing strings?

Comment: Check that you have same type, then I would do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38746242/use-string-parameter-for-regex-in-query/38754322#38754322

Comment: I suspect that, while you think that you are "passing a list of strings", what DB2 sees is a single string value that cannot be converted to a number (the error message indicates that it attempts an implicit conversion to `DECFLOAT`).

Answer (score 2):

I would first verify that by commenting-out the last predicate of the WHERE clause avoids the error; i.e. redact the failing statement such that the IN predicate referencing the Jasper variable as input is no longer part of the query.

Then, determine what defines that variable replacement, from the output of the following query:

  `select  '$p ! {listOfMobileNumbers}' from sysibm.sysdummy1`

If the effect of the above query, used to reveal the data in that *list*, presents something like `'1234,567,890'`, then I would suggest modifying the data that defines that *list* to reflect either of `'1234','567','890'` or `1234, 567, 890` instead.

FWiW: IMO the actual DDL [for column(s) or the TABLE] is much clearer to a reader than suggesting merely that:

> The mobile_number field is returned from the database as a String and not a DECIMAL

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
COALESCE(Count(DISTINCT transaction_entries.transaction_id), 0)
```

with

```
COALESCE(Count(DISTINCT transaction_entries.transaction_id), '0')
```

The problem is that you are trying to convert a decimal/float value to a column that is a string (char, varchar, text, etc). This is common with other statements such as ISNULL and CONCAT. Whenever the statement returns a decimal/float value for a string column, the SqlDataException DECFLOAT will occur.